# Negative one being stored as a value

Tags: sql, ms-access, checkbox

I have a Sql table with integer variables in it.

I am using an Access front end(I know, not my design)

It has many check boxes on it, when its a Checked or True value it is getting stored as a negative one.

Is there a way to have it store as a 1 instead?

Thank you,

Steve

Comment: Is this SQL Server, or another SQL database?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a hidden textbox on the form that is bound to the field.  Then have a visible checkbox on the form that the user interacts with.

When the user checks that box in the `AfterUpdate` assign the `1` or `0` to the hidden textbox which is what is saved in the database:

```
Private Sub chkStatus_AfterUpdate()
  If chkStatus Then txtMyField = 1 Else txtMyField = 0
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the SQL data type to Bit?  How about creating a calculated column and setting the value to 1 if the linked field-value is -1?  If you need to filter on this column, you can persist it, which lets you even use it in an index.

Comment: There were some notes from previous programmer on this that the Bit field was causing some errors/problems when used.  I don't know what, but will have to look at it again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you've used an `integer` type in SQL instead of `bit`?  In MS Access (and Visual Basic for Applications), `True` when cast to an `Integer` is -1, not 1.

In SQL Server, the `bit` data type allows you to store true/false variables in much less space than integer values, and the MS Access front end will automatically store the correct value in the SQL backend based on the checkboxes in the forms and table views.  (And yes, SQL Server's `TRUE` value is 1.)